# Get from external and echo in title

Tags: echo, external, title

i dont know if that is possible.

I want to call a external page and echo like this below.

index.php

```
<?php include 'extern/connect.php';

  $title = file_get_contents('extern/title.php');


 ?>
<head>
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>       //here i want to echo also $a from title.php   
</head>
```

Title.php

```
<?php

$a ="Youtube";
$b ="Facebook";
$c ="Myspace";
$d ="Google";


?>
```

Is that possible ?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a simple include ? It will put the content of your page and interpret it (like what you do on the top of your index.php)